# "Subquery returned more than 1 value" with UPDATE query

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hello I write this sql query to update a table. The query is:

```
Update Product Set MakeId = (Select Distinct v.Id from VehicleCompany v, Car_Window c, product p Where p.ProductSKU = c.mf_part_no
AND c.make = v.Name
Group By v.Id)
```

But whenever I run this query it gives the following error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,
>
> > , >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

May I know Where I'm making the mistake?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Your `Select Distinct` can return multiple values. To assign a value to `MakeId` your subquery must return only 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
Select Distinct v.Id
from VehicleCompany v, Car_Window c, product p
Where p.ProductSKU = c.mf_part_no
AND c.make = v.Name
```

You should see it is bring back more than 1 row and you will need to fix this part of the query

If you are confident the ID will always be the same changing to this will fix it for you:

```
Select top 1 Distinct v.Id from VehicleCompany v, Car_Window c, product p
Where p.ProductSKU = c.mf_part_no
AND c.make = v.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether that's what you want. You could write `(Select Top 1 ...)`